# JQuery mouseOver fades in twice only want once

Tags: jquery, html, css

The version can be shown here. I want the existing text to fade out and the new text to fade in. For some reason this fades in twice weirdly.

```
$(window).load(function(){
var originalTitle = $('.Pinctitle').text();

$('body').on('mouseenter', '.Pselectorbutton', function(){
    var text = $(this).data('title');
    $('.Pinctitle').text(text);
});
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.Pselectorbutton', function(){
    $('.Pinctitle').text(originalTitle);
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ejnxyhke/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ejnxyhke/2/):

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.Pselectorbutton', function(){
    var text = $(this).data('title');
    $('.Pinctitle').stop(1,1).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
        $(this).text(text);
    }).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
});
```

[Also another One.](http://jsfiddle.net/ejnxyhke/6/)

Comment: You beat me by 54 seconds ;-) Do you see any drawback by starting the second animation inside the callback?

Comment: This is perfect. It seems like quite a work around for something I thought would be so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your solution is about asynchronity. You kick off the animation. This call returns immediately and continues with setting the new text. You could use a callback method to overcome this issue like so:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.Pselectorbutton', function(){
    var text = $(this).data('title');
    $('.Pinctitle').text(originalTitle).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
         $('.Pinctitle').text(text).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Cheers for the explanation

Comment: You are welcome. Callbacks come in handy often when using JavaScript, so better get used to them ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The animate function has a call back on complete.  Try that:

```
var originalTitle = $('.Pinctitle').text();

$('body').on('mouseenter', '.Pselectorbutton', function(){
    var text = $(this).data('title');
    var pinc = $('.Pinctitle');
    pinc.text(originalTitle).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', pinc.text(text).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow'));
});
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.Pselectorbutton', function(){
    $('.Pinctitle').text(originalTitle);
});
```